# Array initiliazation

Tags: c++, arrays

Is it illegal declare array without size? Like

```
int n;

int array[n]; 
cin>>n; // assign 5 to n, it will be array with size 5 OR


int n=5; // we assign 5 to n;
int array[n];// int array[5];
```

Question: Which is legal

Comment: If the compiler has this as an extension, the first will not work as it will use whatever value `n` has when being declared. Setting `n` _after_  you declare the array doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried building this or are you just interested as a generic question? This one is pretty simple when you've built it.

Comment: but you can create array like this, int* array = new int[n];

Answer (score 2):

Neither is legal c++. The array's size has to be constant :

```
int n = 5; int a[n]; // NOT legal, since it attempts to use VLA
int b[5];  // OK
```

If it works, it is through an extension. It is allowed in the latest c to use VLA.

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ only allows `const` value for size of an array:

```
int array[5];
```

or:

```
const size_t SIZE = 5;
int array[SIZE];
```

There is an GCC extension that allows for variable length arrays.

Note, it is possible to omit the size of the array if it is being initialised:

```
int array[] = { 67, 12, 88, 94, 37}; // size of 5.
```

As this is C++, consider using `std::vector<int>` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

VLA's aren't supported by C++, as other have mentions you can use manually managed dynamic arrays. BUT DON'T.

You a vector container it has all of the advantages of a dynamic array, except it is safe, resizable and has a decent interface.

```
size_t size;
std::cin >> size;
std::vector<int> arr(size, 0); //starting size, default value

arr[0]; //access elments
arr.at(0); //bounds checked access 
arr.push_bacK(6); add 6 to back, now has 6 elements
```

these is no need to delete anything and there is no chance of leaks.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector